# How can i set variable inside addEventListener Clicked Event?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, click

I want to make a clicked function that recognized the item being click, is that possible? Could you teach me ?^^

Here is my try, but It didn't work:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class main extends MovieClip {
    private var _s1:s1Mc;
    private var _s2:s2Mc;


    public function main() {
        _s1=new s1Mc();
        this.addChild(_s1);
        _s2=new s2Mc();
        this.addChild(_s2);

        _s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF(_s1));
        _s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF(_s2));
    }
    public function ClickedF(e:MouseEvent,$varMc:MovieClip)
    {
        if($varMc==_s1)
        trace("_s1");
        if($varMc==_s2)
        trace("_s2");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Errors:

```
F:\test\click test\main.as, Line 18 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type s1Mc to an unrelated type flash.events:MouseEvent.
F:\test\click test\main.as, Line 18 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 2.
F:\test\click test\main.as, Line 19 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type s2Mc to an unrelated type flash.events:MouseEvent.
F:\test\click test\main.as, Line 19 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 2.
```

I understand that I should set 2 things inside the ClickedF of addEventListener but I really don't know how to do it T_T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one argument in an event handler, but the Event object that comes in has a property `currentTarget`, which is that object that dispatched the event.

```
public function main() {
    _s1=new s1Mc();
    this.addChild(_s1);
    _s2=new s2Mc();
    this.addChild(_s2);

    _s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF);
    _s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF);
}
public function ClickedF(e:MouseEvent)
{ 
    if(e.currentTarget==_s1)
    trace("_s1");
    if(e.currentTarget==_s2)
    trace("_s2");
}
```

Also, by convention you should start your function names with a lowercase character.  Only Class names should start with an uppercase character.  This makes your code easier for others to understand, because by convention `ClickedF` looks like you are passing a reference to a class, not a function.  When working in a team of developers sticking to these standards is essential for productivity and is usually a workplace requirement, so it's best to get into the habit now.

Comment: `target`? Why not `currentTarget`? What if click was performed on inner Sprite or MovieClip?

Comment: @Constantiner - `target` is the object that actually dispatched the event. `currentTarget` is the object that is currently processing the event.  The OP asked to get the object that was clicked on, whereas in a bubbling or event recycling/cloning situation `currentTarget` would return the nearest object, not the one that was clicked.

Comment: The object processing event is the object which `addEventListener` handling now. The object actually dispatched event is the object which user click (so it can be inner MovieClip, so `e.target==_s1` won't be true).

Comment: @Constantiner - apologies, I've just checked and I seem to have it the exact wrong way round.  Will edit the answer.

Comment: +1 for naming conventions. An event handler is usually named using this syntax: `on[ObjectName][EventType]`. If an event handler handles an event for multiple objects it's usually named using the following syntax: `on[EventType]`; or `[eventType]Handler`. In your case I would name your event handler `onClick()` or `clickHandler()`.

Comment: I always prefer `[type]Handler`, because it avoids migration warnings for function names like `onRollOver` and `onEnterFrame`.

Comment: BTW, the official Adobe's coding conventions are [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class main extends MovieClip {
    private var _s1:s1Mc;
    private var _s2:s2Mc;


    public function main() {
        _s1=new s1Mc();
        this.addChild(_s1);
        _s2=new s2Mc();
        this.addChild(_s2);

        _s1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF);
        _s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickedF);
    }
    public function ClickedF(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var $varMc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        if($varMc==_s1)
        trace("_s1");
        if($varMc==_s2)
        trace("_s2");
    }
}
}
```